# Android Add border to rounded Image

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm using below code to make my images rounded, but now I want to add a white border around the circle so there'll be a transparent circle with white border until the image is loaded( I'm using picassa library to load the image remotely from server so sometimes it takes time to load them).

```
public static Bitmap getCroppedImage(Bitmap bmp, int radius)
{
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

The problem is that this code is written by another programmer and I have to extend the code to add white border around the images. but again the white border should be shown regardless of the image loaded or not.

Comment: have a look at that library https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Comment: @MoubeenFarooqWarar Thanks, is there a jar file available for this library or should I just download the project and include it as a library in my project?

Comment: if you are using android studio then just write compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1' line in your build.xml if not then download that project import it and inclucde that (circularimageview) as an library

Comment: and also see the sample demo that will help you

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders I haven't used that library yet to do what I wanted, when I do and it works I'll ask him to make it as an asnwer.